# nginx возвращает 404 на .php в соседней папке

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Вэбсайт mysite.local находится в `/usr/share/nginx/mysite.local`

Дистрибутив метрики Piwik находится в `/usr/share/nginx/piwik`

Доступ в piwik осуществляется через `mysite.local/piwik`

При запросе `mysite.local/piwik` возвращается 404. Если изменить `root` в секции `server` на путь к piwik (закомментированный вариант), то все работает ок.

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 8080;

    server_name mysite.local;

    root        /usr/share/nginx/mysite.local/frontend/web;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/piwik;
    index       index.php index.html;

    access_log  /usr/share/nginx/mysite.local/frontend/log/access.log;
    error_log   /usr/share/nginx/mysite.local/frontend/log/error.log;

    location /piwik {
        root /usr/share/nginx;
        index     index.php;
    }
    location  ~ /piwik/.+\.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/piwik/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }


    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: статические файлы по запросу `/piwic/файл` отдаются нормально?

Comment: Ну логично, откуда бы `try_files` знать, что искать файл нужно в другой папке?

Comment: И ещё, `location` в nginx не «складываются», так что ваш `location /piwik` на PHP-файлы не оказывает никакого влияния.

Comment: аналогичный вопрос: http://serverfault.com/q/317641/292034

Answer (score 1):

на основании ответов к этому вопросу: [nginx: multiple document roots with fastcgi](https://serverfault.com/q/317641/292034)

можно порекомендовать вот в этом фрагменте:

```
location /piwik {
    root /usr/share/nginx;
    index     index.php;
}
location  ~ /piwik/.+\.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/piwik/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

второй из *location*-ов сделать вложенным в первый, соответствующим образом подправив регулярное выражение, используемое в этом *location*-е. примерно так:

```
location /piwik {
  root /usr/share/nginx;
  index     index.php;
  location  ~ .php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/piwik/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #try_files $uri =404;
  }
}
```

и ещё: директива `try_files` в данном месте мне кажется ненужной, поэтому я предлагаю её закомментировать.